# Javascript code execution pausing issue

Tags: javascript, html, time, html5-canvas, sleep

I'm making a little game, and i was making a character death sequence when I ran into this problem. The

```
eloop(setInterval(e_seq,100)
```

plays the ending sequence. After that, I want execution to stop for a second before displaying the score and stuff.
But the current sleep method i'm using pauses the entire execution, including the loop, while I want the loop to be completed before pausing the game for a second.

The place where sleep is called: (inside the main gameloop)

```
eloop=setInterval(e_seq,100);
sleep(1000);
```

The sleep method:

```
function sleep(msec)
{
var time= new Date().getTime();
while(time+msec>= new Date().getTime())
{}
}
```

any solutions?

PS: calling sleep at the end of the gameloop (inside an if condition checker) was pausing the execution before the gameloop began for some reason....

Comment: You should read some documentation about `setTimeout` like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) for example.

Comment: Check out `window.requestAnimationFrame` which is an animation loop that's very efficient.  It sends a time value with each loop that you can use to get fine-grained control of your death sequence. You can use that time value to calculate an elapsed time which you can use to start-pause-restart your animations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want something more along the lines of

```
setTimeout(function () { e_seq(); }, 1000);
```

This would wait one second and then execute the e_seq() function, which I think is the purpose of your code, although it's open to a little interpretation...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just the setInterval?

```
setInterval(function(){ ... }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried something

```
var looper;
var looptime = 2000;

var doloop = function(){
    console.log("doing this")   
}

function begin(callthis){
    looper = setInterval(callthis,looptime);    
}

function pause(callthis,sleeptime){
    clearInterval(looper);
    setTimeout(function(){
        looper = setInterval(callthis,looptime);
    },sleeptime)
}
```

using like:

```
begin(doloop);
```

and pause with

```
pause(doloop,10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback when using "sleep" functionality. The sleep concept does not exist in JavaScript.

You should not use a busy-loop as you do as that will hold off any other processes as well as JavaScript is single threaded (incl. DOM updates). Use a timer instead but as timers are asynchronous you will have to use the mentioned callback.

It's not so complicated -

Modify the sleep method like this:

```
function sleep(timeout, callback) {
    setTimout(callback, timeout);   // or just call this directly...
}
```

(as you can see it's a bit excess with the wrapper so I would recommend just calling the `setTimeout()` directly).

Now you can implement your score screen into a function:

```
function showScores() {
    ...
}
```

Then when you want to delay a second before showing the score screen do:

```
sleep(1000, showScores);
```

or simply:

```
setTimeout(showScores, 1000);
```

Note that the rest of your code will continue after calling this method so make sure all code resides in functions so you can use them as callbacks.